# Wrap_Content of ScrollView inside RelativeLayout generates empty space

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

**Background:**

I have a BottomSheetDialog with RelativeLayout parent. I have a child ScrollView holding a TextView below some views and there is a Bottom TextView below ScrollView. I need the ScrollView to Wrap_Content according to the text size it holds and keep the Bottom TextView at the parent bottom below the ScrollView.
When the ScrollView content is large there is no issue. However when the content is small it generates a gap/empty space between it and Bottom TextView as described in the images.

**What I tried:**

If I use a LinearLayout parent and when the content of the ScrollView is large enough to occupy the whole screen it simply hides the Bottom TextView.
If I don't use layout_above parameter for the ScrollView it simply hides the Bottom TextView when the content is large.
If I remove alignParentBottom for the Bottom TextView it simply gets hidden when the content of ScrollView is larger.

**What I need:**

I want to remove this empty space between ScrollView and TextView as mentioned in the attached image.

**My Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:gravity="start|center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="16dp"

        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pub"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/s_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/downloaded_file_name"
        android:layout_below="@id/s_text"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/downloaded_file_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="end|bottom"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Empty space between ScrollView and TextView]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Android does not support justify ,To justify text in android use WebView

 WebView view = new WebView(this);
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.inset_web_view)).addView(view);

    view.loadData(getString(R.string.hello), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
and html code

<string name="hello">
<![CDATA[
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body style="text-align:justify;color:gray;background-color:black;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
  adipiscing elit. Nunc pellentesque, urna
  nec hendrerit pellentesque, risus massa
 </body>
</html>
]]>
</string>
EDIT: to set Background transparent in it, use:

webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

this.wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 

@Override public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {                
      view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) 
      view.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); } });
```

Comment: I believe there should be a solution for this. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Oreo and newer support justify